# Django CMS Placeholder Within Template Block Not Displaying

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-cms

I am following [this](https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2016/02/16/build-a-website-without-knowing-python-django-part-three/) tutorial on building a basic blog using the Django CMS and am encountering a strange behavior. It all started when I discovered that the Content area was not being created in the Structure section of the CMS. While investigating it, I discovered the strange behavior.

Here it is.

base.html:

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

content.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% placeholder content or%}
    {% endplaceholder %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This configuration above displays no Content block on the Structure page of the CMS. However, if I change the base.html snippet to the following, it works.

base.html:

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                {% placeholder content or%}
                {% endplaceholder %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

Could someone tell me why this happens? What am I missing in how Django handles the template blocks? It appears to me that the two cases should be treated identically. Yet, the result is obviously different. The tutorial claims that I should be changing the content.html side. However, as illustrated above, that does not work.

Any elucidation is appreciated!

Comment: Both indeed appear to be identical, and should work according to me. The only think I can think of is that you might be extending a different base.html. Could you try adding some basic html in content.html to see if it gets rendered?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it did not have any effect. Having played with it for a bit longer, I was able to resolve it. See my answer below, if interested.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using the following modifications.

base.html:

```
<!-- Main Content -->
{% placeholder content or %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
{% endplaceholder %}
```

content.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```